# System.Net.Http could not load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, assemblies

I am currently working on a Web API project where I have a single simple controller that works correctly. I created a Unit Test project to test my API's controller. The project references `System.Net.Http (4.0.0.0)` and `System.Web` assemblies as well as `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Web Host` NuGet package and all its sub-packages. When I run my first `TestMethod` it fails and throws an exception saying:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference.

I tried a lot of things but nothing seemed to solve my issue and there isn't a `System.Net.Http` with version 5.2.2.0 in `References -> Assemblies`. I am currently using Visual Studio Community Edition 2013. Thanks!

Comment: what version does your WebConfig show at /runtime/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[name="System.Web.Http"]?

Comment: First, System.Net != System.Web. Second, try to match your TestProject target framework with the Web Api project, and you should find the correct versions in the References -> Assemblies.

Comment: There isn't a `dependentAssembly` with such name... :/

Comment: My projects use the same Target Framework already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reinstalling the NuGet package `Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Core Libraries` for that project? System.Web.Http 5.2.2.0 is contained in that package. You should be able to see a reference for System.Web.Http under your project references for version 5.2.2.0 or greater if that NuGet package was installed correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! I had to Uninstall the `Web Host` package and install `Core Libraries` manually.

Comment: If someone is not sure: To reinstall, in VS go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console and run

     `Update-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -reinstall`